# can we run Cypress tests in Safari browser and Mobile testing with integration of Saucelabs?

Tags: javascript, protractor, cypress, mobile-safari, saucelabs

my testscripts need to executed in mobile devices and safari browser . with the cypress and sauce labs integration can we achieve mobile testing and safari browser using cypress ?.
currently my test scripts in protractor and running all browsers like safari and mobile devices with integration of sauce labs.(Currently we are running scripts with  Protractor+Saucelabs+Jenkins)

As Protractor deprecated by end of 2022, we want to migrate existing code from protractor to cypress . Can some please confirm can we achieve safari browser,mobile testing.future we want to run(Cypress+Saucelabs+Jenkins).
Please suggest.

Comment: Safari is currently not supported. However if you are looking for web mobile testing, you can alter the `userAgent` by configuration to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress doesn’t support Safari at the moment, so the answer is no

Comment: with the integration of sauce labs can we achieve safari browser and mobile testing. can you please confirm on mobile also ?

Comment: Sauce Labs can only support what Cypress supports, to if Cypress doesn't support mobile and Safari, then Sauce Labs can also not support it. The technology used by Cypress is the "limiting factor" here, not Sauce Labs.

Answer (score 1):

Since Cypress v10.8, it is possible to run tests in WebKit (the browser engine used in Safari). Currently, the support for WebKit is experimental and can be enabled by following 2 steps:

1. set `experimentalWebKitSupport` to `true` in the Cypress config
2. install the `playwright-webkit` npm package

You can find more details in the official Cypress release: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2022/09/13/cypress-10-8-experimental-run-tests-in-webkit/